# "Зарываться" - этимология

Tags: этимология

О человеке, который переступил грань дозволенного, обнаглел, говорят "он зарвался". А вот интересно было бы узнать происхождения этого слова.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ

ЗАРВАТЬСЯ,  Разг.-сниж.
Зайти в своих действиях слишком далеко, потеряв чувство меры в оценке своих сил, возможностей и т.п. Кто-л. ни с кем не считается. Совсем зарвался.

ЗАРВАТЬСЯ. Искон. Преф. производное от рваться "стремиться к чему-л.", ср. вырваться (вперед), оторваться (от конкурентов).

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Значение слова можно считать с его морфемного состава. Приставка "ЗА" обычно используется для образования глаголов совершенного вида и обозначает результат действия: готовить - заготовить, морозить - заморозить. Однако в некоторых случаях  она приобретает значение "довести действие до отрицательного состояния": кормить - закормить, таскать - затаскать, гонять - загонять. Вот и в нашем случае излишняя устремленность вперед может привести к отрицательным последствиям.

Comment: "Зарваться" от "рвение"?

Comment: РВЕНИЕ (от рваться) - сильное стремление, большое усердие.  Однако в исключительно положительном значении употребляется не часто, например: «Прочтите в переписке Репина словесные зарисовки разных городов, и вы увидите, как непреодолимо было его рвение к писательству». Чаще рвение мы связываем с карьеризмом или вообще считаем, что оно приносит вред: "Его рвение не осталось незамеченным: Костика повысили в должности. Он сказал это  голосом, в котором так и звенело служебное рвение. Может, причиной тому стали его чудачества. А может, чрезмерное рвение, даже фанатизм. Пора их рвение укоротить".